# Onchanges get the values from jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

While on change i want to change the span values. Please check the below code.
Getting the values from databases using php

```
    <input type="text" name="no_guest_conferance" class="conf_guest" id="no_guest_conferance" placeholder="Enter no. of guest" value ="<?php if(isset($con_details[0]['min_seating_capacity'])){echo $con_details[0]['min_seating_capacity'];}?>"/>
<span style="float:left; margin-bottom:14px;" id="conference_subtotal">
    <span id="conferencesubtotal"><?php echo 'Rs. '.number_format(ceil($subTotal),0); ?> </span>
    <span style="font-size:12px;" >Sub Total</span>
 </span>
```

Script here.

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("input").change(function(){
          var val=$(this).val();
          var price=$('#price').val();
          var subtotal=val*price;
          $("#conferencesubtotal").val(subtotal);
        });
    });
    </script>
```

I didn't get the value here?please tell me where i mistake.

Comment: `var price=$('#price').val();`? where this `price` element come from> i didn't see it in your  your html code?

Answer (score 1):

Use blur instead of change and to print value in span use text or html instead of the val, val will work for input only.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".conf_guest").blur(function(){
            var val=$(this).val();
            var price=$('#price').val();
            var subtotal=val*price;
            $("#conferencesubtotal").text(subtotal);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

On span use [text()](http://api.jquery.com/text) not [val()](http://api.jquery.com/val) and apply onchange event only on your Guest conference number field like,

```
$("input#no_guest_conferance").change(function() {
    var val = Number(this.value);
    var price = Number($('#price').val());
    var subtotal = val * price;
    $("#conferencesubtotal").text(subtotal);
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input#no_guest_conferance").change(function() {
    var val = Number(this.value);
    var price = Number($('#price').val());
    var subtotal = val * price;
    $("#conferencesubtotal").text(subtotal);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="no_guest_conferance" class="conf_guest" id="no_guest_conferance" placeholder="Enter no. of guest" value="1" />
<input type="text" name="price" class="conf_guest" id="price" placeholder="Price" value="10" disabled="disabled"/>
<span style="float:left; margin-bottom:14px;" id="conference_subtotal">
    <span id="conferencesubtotal"></span>
<span style="font-size:12px;">Sub Total</span>
</span>
```

Comment: if i enter 2 in guest and 100 in price and then i move my cursor from 100 to 2 it gives 10000 which is not correct:- http://prntscr.com/cenyue

Comment: Thanks @Anant for pointing it out. Actually I just used the same code as OP used and forgot to change the selector on which the `change event` applied. Also there is no element for `price` in the question, so I've added it as a text field an applied change event on all inputs which was wrong in that case.

Answer (score 0):

you can get the value from 
     `$("#conferencesubtotal").html(subtotal);`

`.val()` work only on `input`, `select` and `textarea`. [jquery .val() doc](http://api.jquery.com/val/)

Answer (score 0):

Change the following line:

```
$("#conferencesubtotal").val(subtotal);
```

to

```
$("#conferencesubtotal").text(subtotal);
```

because span tag do not have a value attribute in it. The value it shows is its text, so provide your value in text()